# Remove Index on ActiveRecord[5.1] replacing model_id with nil

Tags: ruby-on-rails, activerecord, sqlite3-ruby

I am trying to remove a reference column from my database, locally using sqlite3.

Was getting the `SQLite3::ConstraintException: FOREIGN KEY constraint failed: DROP TABLE "features"` so I tried removing the foreign key first. That did not change anything in my schema file, other than the version because a migration was successfully run.

Now trying

```
def up
  remove_index :features, column: [:user_id]
end

def down
  add_index :features, column: [:user_id]
end
```

And this replaces 
`t.index ["user_id"], name: "index_features_on_user_id"`
with `t.index [nil], name: "index_features_on_user"`

I tried playing with the remove_index to be just `:user` or `:user_id` as the second parameter, but no luck.

I even tried to add a name and the same nil `remove_index :features, :user_id, name: :index_features_on_user`

Ultimately I want to remove the entire reference to user, the `t.index` and the `t.integer "user_id"`, but have not been successful and thought it was because there was that index sitting there refusing to be deleted, but I could be wrong.

**UPDATE**

Here is the features table

```
  create_table "features", force: :cascade do |t|
    t.integer "instance_id"
    t.integer "user_id"
    t.integer "experiment_id"
    t.string "name"
    t.text "values"
    t.datetime "created_at", null: false
    t.datetime "updated_at", null: false
    t.boolean "is_allow_na", default: false, null: false
    t.index ["experiment_id"], name: "index_features_on_experiment_id"
    t.index ["instance_id"], name: "index_features_on_instance_id"
    t.index ["user_id"], name: "index_features_on_user_id"
  end
```

Comment: can you give more information about the model of the table you are dropping ?

Comment: is there another tables that have foreign keys referencing the table you are trying to drop?

Comment: It was created with `t.belongs_to :user` I tried dropping FK's, migration was successful but nothing changed in the schema.

Comment: All I want to do is reverse the t.belongs_to column and whatever it created

Comment: how does your to tables look like can I see their columns in the schema.rb, plus the content of both models

Comment: this migration can be reversed by rails it self it will now how to reverse it since it is not something complex that it can not reverse. however your problem could be with the data residing in your table so a look at your models and tables columns could help.

Comment: Thanks Abdullah, updated what the table looks like in the schema. I appreciate your help

Comment: does your feature model have has_many relations with other models ?

Comment: a possible cause of the problem that there might be another table having `feature_id` reference in it to the feature table so the foreign key in that table is not allowing the drop of features table.

Comment: The feature model has has relationships with experiments, instances, and yes the feature_id belongs to other tables. But I can't be expected to remove all that just for one simple column deletion? Does that mean the reference is there forever now?

Comment: since there is a `feature_id` column in other tables that means the feature table is a parent table to them. and the foreign key on the `feature_id` on the other table is what is causing this error. since you need to move this table make sure you remove any foreign keys on the tables that are referencing `features` table. actually since the table is going to be dropped then there is no meaning for the `feature_id` column to exist on them anymore since it has no benefit to keep it after dropping the table. so you have to remove it from all tables in in the migrations before you drop your table.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/212609/discussion-between-madav-and-abdullah-fadhel).

Comment: removing the foreign key from the other tables referencing the feature table will do the trick. but as I said you better delete the column since it will no longer be useful.